# Get Column of MySql-Query as headline only once in PHP (even if there are several results)

Tags: php, mysql, fluid, extbase

So, how the name already says or not says, because i did not really know how to name my issue, i am trying to achieve the following thing.

I got a MySQL-Query which delivers me a result like this:

```
id | name     | position
1    Kevin      CEO
2    Sarah      Developer
3    Daniel     Developer
4    Michael    Marketing
5    Tom        Marketing
```

Now i need to show the information in Frontend like this:

```
**CEO**
Kevin

**Developer**
Sarah
Daniel

**Marketing**
Michael
Tom
```

Which means i need the position-column only once as a headline, and under it i want to show the matching persons for this position.
It is no option for me to do a separate query for every position because in my table i have like 75 of it.

So how can i achieve it to, on one side, get the `position`s of my query result only once as a headline, and on the other side, get every person's `name` for this position listed under it.

I hope i was able to explain my problem good enough.

Comment: Do you want a query to return result as you provided? If yes, then is bad approach because it should be done in application layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop once through the result and make the position a key in a new array.

```
$newArray = [];

foreach($myQueryResult as $res){
    $newArray[$res['position']][] = $res['name'];
}
```

This results in this output:

```
Array (
   "CEO" => [ "kevin" ],
   "Developer" => [ "Sarah", "Daniel" ],
   "Marketing" => [ "Michael", "Tom" ]
)
```

Comment: I tried this and this is doing the job! Thank you a lot :) I will accept your answer as soon as i can.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT `position`, GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR '<br>') as name FROM `YourTableName` GROUP BY `position`
```